# How to instantiate a non-public final class using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a non-public final class that looks like the following:

```
final class FragmentManagerImpl {
    ...
}
```

Note that it is not public and it has no declared constructors.

I would like to instantiate an instance of this class using reflection.  However, both of the following code snippets result in IllegalAccessExceptions:

```
        // BUG IllegalAccessException on calling newInstance
        final Class c = Class.forName("android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl");
        c.newInstance();

        // BUG IllegalAccessException on calling newInstance
        final Class c = Class.forName("android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl");
        final Constructor constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        constructor.newInstance();
```

What is the correct way to instantiate this class from a package that is not android.support.v4.app?

Comment: i tried twice, second time put the NoConstructorClass in a totally different package. you second way runs correct on my jdk6+eclipse.

Comment: Thank you swanliu, I agree.  It appears to have been user error, see my answer below.  Unfortunately, SO won't let me delete the question, mark my answer correct, or vote it up yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it appears to have been user error.  Using the constructor method outlined in the question does seem to have worked properly.

Answer (score 3):

According to [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), you can call getDeclaredConstructors() method and you'll get all the private constructors as well as the default constructor.

> public Constructor[] getDeclaredConstructors()
>                                            throws SecurityException
>
> ```
> Returns an array of Constructor objects reflecting all the
> ```
>
> constructors declared by the class represented by this Class object.
>   These are public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   constructors. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and
>   are not in any particular order. If the class has a default
>   constructor, it is included in the returned array. This method returns
>   an array of length 0 if this Class object represents an interface, a
>   primitive type, an array class, or void.
>
> ```
> See The Java Language Specification, section 8.2.
> ```

It doesn't specify how exactly this getDeclaredConstructor(Class... parameterTypes) method, that you are using, will work though.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're suggesting the fix is.

Comment: I am suggesting to call the getDeclaredConstructors() method instead and iterate through the list to see if you can see any constructor.

Comment: Yes, I can see the default constructor.

Comment: I assume you will still get an IllegalAccessException if you try to create a new instance using this one. This is because you don't have access the definition of the class. The class is package protected and there is no way (AFAIK) you can make an instance out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but I think that it is complaining about the accessibility of the class not (just) the constructor.

Try calling `setAccessible(true)` on the `Class` object as well as the `Constructor` object.

Comment: I do not believe that Class has a setAccessible() method